# Python vigenereHacker program fails with raw_input

Tags: python, raw-input

[I have posted this question once, but i failed to include necessary information, which I am sorry for, this is my first time on Stack overflow]

Ok, I have python2.7 and a pdf book entitled Hacking secret ciphers with python, and it  has this code in it:

```
import itertools, re
import vigenereCipher, pyperclip, freqAnalysis, detectEnglish
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
SILENT_MODE = False # if set to True, program doesn't print attempts
NUM_MOST_FREQ_LETTERS = 4 # attempts this many letters per subkey
MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 16 # will not attempt keys longer than this
NONLETTERS_PATTERN = re.compile('[^A-Z]')
def main():
    # Instead of typing this ciphertext out, you can copy & paste it
    # from http://invpy.com/vigenereHacker.py
    ciphertext = """Adiz Avtzqeci Tmzubb wsa m Pmilqev halpqavtakuoi, lgouqdaf, kdmktsvmztsl, izr xoexghzr kkusitaaf."""
    hackedMessage = hackVigenere(ciphertext)

    if hackedMessage != None:
        print('Copying hacked message to clipboard:')
        print(hackedMessage)
        pyperclip.copy(hackedMessage)
    else:
        print('Failed to hack encryption.')
def findRepeatSequencesSpacings(message):
    # Goes through the message and finds any 3 to 5 letter sequences
    # that are repeated. Returns a dict with the keys of the sequence and
    # values of a list of spacings (num of letters between the repeats).
    # Use a regular expression to remove non-letters from the message.
    message = NONLETTERS_PATTERN.sub('', message.upper())
    # Compile a list of seqLen-letter sequences found in the message.
    seqSpacings = {} # keys are sequences, values are list of int spacings
    for seqLen in range(3, 6):
        for seqStart in range(len(message) - seqLen):
            # Determine what the sequence is, and store it in seq
            seq = message[seqStart:seqStart + seqLen]
            # Look for this sequence in the rest of the message
            for i in range(seqStart + seqLen, len(message) - seqLen):
                if message[i:i + seqLen] == seq:
                    # Found a repeated sequence.
                    if seq not in seqSpacings:
                        seqSpacings[seq] = [] # initialize blank list
                    # Append the spacing distance between the repeated
                    # sequence and the original sequence.
                    seqSpacings[seq].append(i - seqStart)
    return seqSpacings
def getUsefulFactors(num):
    # Returns a list of useful factors of num. By "useful" we mean factors
    # less than MAX_KEY_LENGTH + 1. For example, getUsefulFactors(144)
    # returns [2, 72, 3, 48, 4, 36, 6, 24, 8, 18, 9, 16, 12]
    if num < 2:
        return [] # numbers less than 2 have no useful factors
    factors = [] # the list of factors found
    # When finding factors, you only need to check the integers up to
    # MAX_KEY_LENGTH.
    for i in range(2, MAX_KEY_LENGTH + 1): # don't test 1
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            factors.append(int(num / i))
    if 1 in factors:
        factors.remove(1)
    return list(set(factors))
def getItemAtIndexOne(x):
    return x[1]
def getMostCommonFactors(seqFactors):
    # First, get a count of how many times a factor occurs in seqFactors.
    factorCounts = {} # key is a factor, value is how often if occurs
    # seqFactors keys are sequences, values are lists of factors of the
    # spacings. seqFactors has a value like: {'GFD': [2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12,
    # 18, 23, 36, 46, 69, 92, 138, 207], 'ALW': [2, 3, 4, 6, ...], ...}
    for seq in seqFactors:
        factorList = seqFactors[seq]
        for factor in factorList:
            if factor not in factorCounts:
                factorCounts[factor] = 0
            factorCounts[factor] += 1
    # Second, put the factor and its count into a tuple, and make a list
    # of these tuples so we can sort them.
    factorsByCount = []
    for factor in factorCounts:
        # exclude factors larger than MAX_KEY_LENGTH
        if factor <= MAX_KEY_LENGTH:
            # factorsByCount is a list of tuples: (factor, factorCount)
            # factorsByCount has a value like: [(3, 497), (2, 487), ...]
            factorsByCount.append( (factor, factorCounts[factor]) )
    # Sort the list by the factor count.
    factorsByCount.sort(key=getItemAtIndexOne, reverse=True)
    return factorsByCount
def kasiskiExamination(ciphertext):
    # Find out the sequences of 3 to 5 letters that occur multiple times
    # in the ciphertext. repeatedSeqSpacings has a value like:
    # {'EXG': [192], 'NAF': [339, 972, 633], ... }
    repeatedSeqSpacings = findRepeatSequencesSpacings(ciphertext)
    # See getMostCommonFactors() for a description of seqFactors.
    seqFactors = {}
    for seq in repeatedSeqSpacings:
        seqFactors[seq] = []
        for spacing in repeatedSeqSpacings[seq]:
            seqFactors[seq].extend(getUsefulFactors(spacing))
    # See getMostCommonFactors() for a description of factorsByCount.
    factorsByCount = getMostCommonFactors(seqFactors)
    # Now we extract the factor counts from factorsByCount and
    # put them in allLikelyKeyLengths so that they are easier to
    # use later.
    allLikelyKeyLengths = []
    for twoIntTuple in factorsByCount:
        allLikelyKeyLengths.append(twoIntTuple[0])
    return allLikelyKeyLengths
def getNthSubkeysLetters(n, keyLength, message):
    # Returns every Nth letter for each keyLength set of letters in text.
    # E.g. getNthSubkeysLetters(1, 3, 'ABCABCABC') returns 'AAA'
    #      getNthSubkeysLetters(2, 3, 'ABCABCABC') returns 'BBB'
    #      getNthSubkeysLetters(3, 3, 'ABCABCABC') returns 'CCC'
    #      getNthSubkeysLetters(1, 5, 'ABCDEFGHI') returns 'AF'
    # Use a regular expression to remove non-letters from the message.
    message = NONLETTERS_PATTERN.sub('', message)
    i = n - 1
    letters = []
    while i < len(message):
    letters.append(message[i])
    i += keyLength
    return ''.join(letters)
def attemptHackWithKeyLength(ciphertext, mostLikelyKeyLength):
    # Determine the most likely letters for each letter in the key.
    ciphertextUp = ciphertext.upper()
    # allFreqScores is a list of mostLikelyKeyLength number of lists.
    # These inner lists are the freqScores lists.
    allFreqScores = []
    for nth in range(1, mostLikelyKeyLength + 1):
        nthLetters = getNthSubkeysLetters(nth, mostLikelyKeyLength, ciphertextUp)
        # freqScores is a list of tuples like:
        # [(<letter>, <Eng. Freq. match score>), ... ]
        # List is sorted by match score. Higher score means better match.
        # See the englishFreqMatchScore() comments in freqAnalysis.py.
        freqScores = []
        for possibleKey in LETTERS:
            decryptedText = vigenereCipher.decryptMessage(possibleKey, nthLetters)
            keyAndFreqMatchTuple = (possibleKey, freqAnalysis.englishFreqMatchScore(decryptedText))
            freqScores.append(keyAndFreqMatchTuple)
        # Sort by match score
        freqScores.sort(key=getItemAtIndexOne, reverse=True)
        allFreqScores.append(freqScores[:NUM_MOST_FREQ_LETTERS])
    if not SILENT_MODE:
        for i in range(len(allFreqScores)):
            # use i + 1 so the first letter is not called the "0th" letter
            print('Possible letters for letter %s of the key: ' % (i + 1))
            for freqScore in allFreqScores[i]:
                print('%s ' % freqScore[0])
            print() # print a newline
    # Try every combination of the most likely letters for each position
    # in the key.
    for indexes in itertools.product(range(NUM_MOST_FREQ_LETTERS), repeat=mostLikelyKeyLength):
        # Create a possible key from the letters in allFreqScores
        possibleKey = ''
        for i in range(mostLikelyKeyLength):
            possibleKey += allFreqScores[i][indexes[i]][0]
        if not SILENT_MODE:
            print('Attempting with key: %s' % (possibleKey))
        decryptedText = vigenereCipher.decryptMessage(possibleKey, ciphertextUp)
        if detectEnglish.isEnglish(decryptedText):
            # Set the hacked ciphertext to the original casing.
            origCase = []
            for i in range(len(ciphertext)):
                if ciphertext[i].isupper():
                    origCase.append(decryptedText[i].upper())
                else:
                    origCase.append(decryptedText[i].lower())
            decryptedText = ''.join(origCase)
        # Check with user to see if the key has been found.
            print('Possible encryption hack with key %s:' % (possibleKey))
            print(decryptedText[:200]) # only show first 200 characters
            print()
            print('Enter D for done, or just press Enter to continue hacking:')
            response = input('> ')
            if response.strip().upper().startswith('D'):
                return decryptedText
# No English-looking decryption found, so return None.
    return None
def hackVigenere(ciphertext):
# First, we need to do Kasiski Examination to figure out what the
# length of the ciphertext's encryption key is.
    allLikelyKeyLengths = kasiskiExamination(ciphertext)
    if not SILENT_MODE:
        keyLengthStr = ''
        for keyLength in allLikelyKeyLengths:
            keyLengthStr += '%s ' % (keyLength)
        print('Kasiski Examination results say the most likely key lengths are: ' + keyLengthStr + '\n')
    for keyLength in allLikelyKeyLengths:
        if not SILENT_MODE:
            print('Attempting hack with key length %s (%s possible keys)...' % (keyLength, NUM_MOST_FREQ_LETTERS ** keyLength))
        hackedMessage = attemptHackWithKeyLength(ciphertext, keyLength)
        if hackedMessage != None:
            break
    # If none of the key lengths we found using Kasiski Examination
    # worked, start brute-forcing through key lengths.
    if hackedMessage == None:
        if not SILENT_MODE:
            print('Unable to hack message with likely key length(s). Brute forcing key length...')
        for keyLength in range(1, MAX_KEY_LENGTH + 1):
            # don't re-check key lengths already tried from Kasiski
            if keyLength not in allLikelyKeyLengths:
                if not SILENT_MODE:
                    print('Attempting hack with key length %s (%s possible keys)...' % (keyLength, NUM_MOST_FREQ_LETTERS ** keyLength))
                hackedMessage = attemptHackWithKeyLength(ciphertext, keyLength)
                if hackedMessage != None:
                    break
    return hackedMessage
# If vigenereHacker.py is run (instead of imported as a module) call
# the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This program works great, but its hard to copy the message to the file every time, so when I change ciphertext = '''etc''' to ciphertext = raw_input("Message:") I get this error:

```
Message:eurbvrebv
Kasiski Examination results say the most likely key lengths are: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vigenereHacker.py", line 206, in <module>
    main()
  File "vigenereHacker.py", line 12, in main
    hackedMessage = hackVigenere(ciphertext)
  File "vigenereHacker.py", line 191, in hackVigenere
    if hackedMessage == None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hackedMessage' referenced before assignment
```

The only difference is the raw_input for ciphertext. Why would this happen and how can I fix it? Thank you

Section of book on this:[Here](https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter21.html)
All libraries and source code:[Here also](https://inventwithpython.com/hackingciphers.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this line:

```
for keyLength in allLikelyKeyLengths:
```

you should have a:

```
hackedMessage == None
```

This is because at line:

```
if hackedMessage == None:
```

you are attempting to use a variable which was never initialized.